# Syncing between the trunk and a branch with SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a new version branch and my trunk.
Whenever I commit a bug fix or an enhancement related to the current version I would like it to automatically sync between the trunk and the new version branch and let me resolve conflicts as I please.
How can it be done?

Comment: This thread is also helpful.
<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547142/svn-automate-merge-of-trunk-into-branch>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click on destination folder (or shall we say destination working copy) > Merge. Choose first option, "Merge a range of revisions" and click Next. Choose source URL, pick revisions you want to merge form URL to working copy, and click Next. Click Test merge to see what will happen, and if all is OK then click Merge.

Edit: Automatic merging is not possible. It has to be done manually for every commit. This is a good thing, because you get to choose which revisions you want merged, and which are to be skipped. If you want all revisions always merged then SVN is bad system to implement this. It is better to have two projects in single trunk with common folders that contain files for both projects, and specific folders that contain files for specific projects. When you change a common file it will be automatically changed for all projects that use it.